# how to send mail with high importance in vb.net

Tags: vb.net, email

I have code for sending an Email:

```
Try
            Dim SmtpServer As New SmtpClient()
            SmtpServer.Credentials = New Net.NetworkCredential("jasibs002@gmail.com", "solutions")
            SmtpServer.Port = 25
            SmtpServer.Host = "smtp.gmail.com"
            SmtpServer.EnableSsl = True
            Dim omail As New MailMessage()
 omail.From = New MailAddress("jasibs002@gmail.com", "JaseemBinBacker", System.Text.Encoding.UTF8)

            omail.Subject = "test subject"
            omail.Body = "Hai How Are You I am Sendig This Mail for Testing"
            '  omail.To.Add("jaseem@ibsdubai.ae")
            omail.To.Add(txtEmail.Text)

            SmtpServer.SendAsync(omail, Nothing)
 Catch ex As Exception
            MsgBox(ex.ToString)
        End Try
```

This is working fine, but while sending email to outlook is there any way mention "High Importance"? I attached image of one high Importance email[image]. Like that one exclamation mark in red color I suppose to do here??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

omail.Priority = MailPriority.Low

ref: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mail.mailmessage.priority.aspx

Answer (score 1):

There is a Priority property in the MailMessage class that you can fill with the following enumeration :
High
Low
Normal

So you can set it as :

```
omail.Priority = MailPriority.High
```